# REST Yii. Как использовать расширение RESTFullYii?

Tags: php, yii, rest, backbone.js

расширение https://github.com/evan108108/RESTFullYii
Расширение, как я понял, реализует REST без надобности настраивать его руками. Но по документации я не совсем понял, как мне использовать это в реальной жизни. На первый взгляд кажется, что нужно погенерировать модели, создать екшены и ... PROFIT. 
У кого есть опыт работы с этим расширением? У меня достаточно сложный фронт-енд на backbone и мало времени на чтение документации. Иначе я бы хотел сам реализовать функциональность RESTfull сервера. 
Поделитесь опытом.

Answer (score 1):

Если надо в backbone отойти от стандартного подхода, то переопредели Backbone.sync

Посмотри исходный код данного метода. Там довольно просто разобрать.